# Command raised an exception: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ' '

Tags: python

I keep getting the error "Command raised an exception: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '' "

This is my code:

```python
    else:
        r.write('1')
        x = int(r.read())
        y = 1000000
        while x<y:
            time.sleep(2)
            x=x+1
            await client.say(x)
            r.write(x)
        if x==y:
            await client.say('Reached one million')
            quit()
```

What would be the best way to fix this?

Comment: What do you get if you `print(r.read())`?

Comment: @CoryKramer judging from the error message in the title it'll be `''` (the empty string)

Comment: I printed it and i just get ' ' but if i go into the text file theres '1'

Comment: Yeah, that's because you're not seeking... `r.write('1'); r.seek(0); r.read()` is probably what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are presumably writing and reading to a file (using a file descriptor), but for that, you have to move the "head" of the stream. You can get the current position by the `r.tell()` method and the `r.seek(<offset>)` method will set it to the desired position. Using `r.seek(0)` will set it to the beginning of the file descriptor.

```
else:
    r.write('1')
    r.seek(0) # Moves the current position back to 0
    x = int(r.read())
    y = 1000000
    while x<y:
        time.sleep(2)
        x = x+1
        await client.say(x)
        r.write(x)
    if x==y:
        await client.say('Reached one million')
        quit()
```

Comment: move the head? code formatting (Ctrl+K) please. dont you think x is non numeric resulting in error?

Comment: Sorry, I was on the phone. x could be a non-numeric value, that's true, but reading through the current example code you can see, that the author of the question clearly wrote a numeric value to the stream, but if you want to read from the same stream as you are writing to you have to move the position of the reading "head" in the file.

Comment: thanks for updating , please surround `` for the code lines in paragraph. ex : r.seek(0) to `\`r.seek(0)`\`

Comment: Done. Thanks for pointing these out, this was actually my first answer on stackoverflow and just quickly wanted to add my thoughts.